# Ford Mondeo 2.0 tdci mk4 2008.

Tags: ford, mondeo

I taken air intake pipe off air filter and drove for around 5 seconds, loss of power now won't rev passed 1000rpm. I have no fault codes what so ever. When i start the car it don't smoke but if i manage to drive a little it smokes like mad

Comment: What is your Question please?

Comment: Did you make certain the airflow meter is connected, and there are no huge leaks?